# How to match classes of "boolean"  types and "Boolean" types?

Tags: scala, reflection, autoboxing

Consider the following code:

```
object U { def foo(s:String) = true }
val boolType = Class.forName("java.lang.Boolean")    
val retType = U.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == "foo").get.getReturnType
boolType == retType // evaluates to false (*)
println (boolType) // prints "class java.lang.Boolean"
println (retType) // prints "boolean"
```

I would like `retType` to match with `boolType` in the line marked `(*)`. How do I automatically equate classes of boxed and unboxed types?

[Edit:] I don't think this is the best solution, but one way is to make the comparison 
`retType.getCanonicalName == "boolean"`

[Edit2:] The context: I am writing some code to automatically invoke a method based on a form name. The code should extract the return types etc from the method and return the appropriate answer. As an example, the following snippet is used:

```
object someObject {}
val validTypes:Array[Class[_]] = Array(Class.forName("java.lang.String"), 
                              someObject.getClass, 
                              Class.forName("java.lang.Boolean"))
object U { def foo(s:String) = true } // can contain more methods 

def getRetType(name:String) = 
  U.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == name).get.getReturnType

println ("Type is "+(if (validTypes.contains(getRetType("foo"))) "valid" else "invalid"))
```

Comment: Interesting question, but in what context do you need it ? Do you want to have it check at compile time or at runtime ?

Comment: @paradigmatic I think the check will be done at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Java reflection wants to represent a primitive return type, it uses `Class` instances that are not the same as the wrapper classes. So in Java, a `boolean` return type is represented by a `java.lang.Boolean.TYPE` (which in Java is also accessible as `boolean.class`, and in Scala as `classOf[Boolean]`).

So you want

```
scala> U.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == "foo").get.getReturnType ==
     java.lang.Boolean.TYPE
res7: Boolean = true
```

Edit : I guess that comparing with `classOf[Boolean]` would be a less JVM specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

On the JVM, `java.lang.Boolean` is the reference type. Your routine returns a scala `Boolean`, which is java primitive `boolean`. That one is not a class in the JVM. Its type is `java.lang.Boolean.TYPE`, not `classOf[Boolean]` (`java.lang.Boolean.class` in java), which is what you get with `Class.forName("java.lang.Boolean")`.

Comment: The class of the Java primitive boolean is boolean.class, and it does indeed exist in the JVM.

Comment: I don't think this says it doesn't exist - it says the primitive isn't a class.

Answer (score 2):

I think your only solution is to have an explicit mapping.
Since you ask how to "(automatically) equate classes of boxed and unboxed types", I show an elegant way to define a comparison function.

First, instead of `Class.forName` you can use `classOf[Type]`, when the type is known at compile-time. Using this, you can define a canonicalizing mapping of unboxed to boxed types:

```
import java.{lang => jl}
val map = Map[Class[_], Class[_]](classOf[Boolean] -> classOf[jl.Boolean],
  classOf[Int] -> classOf[jl.Integer]) //XXX add other entries
```

Then you can define a comparison function:

```
def cmp(lhs: Class[_], rhs: Class[_]) =
  //Canonicalize before comparing
  map.getOrElse(lhs, lhs) == map.getOrElse(rhs, rhs)
```

And test it:

```
scala> cmp(classOf[Boolean], classOf[jl.Boolean])
cmp(classOf[Boolean], classOf[jl.Boolean])
res13: Boolean = true
scala> cmp(classOf[Boolean], classOf[jl.Integer])
cmp(classOf[Boolean], classOf[jl.Integer])
res16: Boolean = false
```

To clarify the relation between `classOf` and `Boolean.TYPE`, here's a couple REPL interactions:

```
scala> classOf[java.lang.Boolean] == java.lang.Boolean.TYPE
res7: Boolean = false

scala> classOf[Boolean] == java.lang.Boolean.TYPE
res8: Boolean = true
```